# How do I create and exception to a puppet catalog?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

How do I create and exception to a puppet catalog?

Specifically I want to use Puppet to manage a one-off set of firewall rules, to be combined with the default ruleset.

This is for a single legacy system only, it should get the default set of rules, AND several additional rules.

It seems silly to me to put this on the puppet master, since it truly will only ever be a one-off thing...   Can I put this in the modules directory on the local machine?   Will Pupped comile a catalog from the server *and* from the local machine?

Thanks for your help

Bill

Answer (score 0):

You could just check from your firewall script if exists localy other script with several additional rules, and, if exists, execute it.
Then, just put your external scipt in right place and go on.
In such way you'll have universal firewall for all servers and custom editions, where you want them to be.